# Cant redirect stdout, stderr to another logger in Celery

Tags: python, celery

Cant redirect stdout to another logger in Celery, I have created special logger objects for Celery with special Handler. And I want to catch all exception occured when task are executed. I add handler for setup_logging signal in celery, to install my own loggers:

```
import sys
import logging.config

from pika.adapters import BlockingConnection
from pika.connection import ConnectionParameters
from pika import BasicProperties

from celery.signals import setup_logging, after_setup_logger


class RabbitMqHandler(logging.Handler):
    '''
    Special logging handler which stores log messages in RabbitMq server
    It can used for async delivering message to clients
    '''

    HOST = 'localhost'
    QUEUE = 'hermes.standard'

    def emit(self, record):
        con = BlockingConnection(ConnectionParameters(self.HOST))
        # Open the channel
        channel = con.channel()

        # Declare the queue
        channel.queue_declare(queue=self.QUEUE, durable=True,
                              exclusive=False, auto_delete=False)

        channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key=self.QUEUE, body=self.format(record)) #','.join(dir(record)))
        con.close()


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
        'timed': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s] %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'console':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'timed'
        },
        'rabbit': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logconfig.RabbitMqHandler',
            'formatter': 'timed'
        },
        'celery': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '1.log',
            'formatter': 'timed',
            }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'celery': {
            'handlers': ['celery'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'hermes': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'rabbit'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        }
    }
}

from celery.log import LoggingProxy

@setup_logging.connect
def setup_logconfig(**kwargs):
    logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
    #return logging.getLogger('hermes')
```

My own logger named 'hermes' works properly, but all exception occured catch standard celery's logger name=celery. I tried to overrride with setting:

CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS =False

But it doesn't works also. All exception goes to standard celery logger.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this issue four years later :-) ?